# User URLs based on the usernames

Tags: 7, users, uri

Is there a module that changes the user URL from "user/1" to "user/username"?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/user-profile-url-editable-by-user-itself

This is the best answer... and just make small difference related to user path to [user:name]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) does exactly that.

All new user aliases generated after enabling the module will look like `users/[user:name]` (obviously this could be changed in module configuration - Configuration / URL aliases / Patterns).

You can use "Bulk update" to generate aliases for already existing users (and other type of content).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [PathAuto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module to create an alias for every user.Your alias pattern would be able to include the username in its pattern.
If you want the aliased path to be the primary url then you can also use [GlobalRedirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) to make user/id redirect to user/username

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the [Me Aliases](http://drupal.org/project/me) module. It doesn't matter what user is logged in; they can use "user/me" to access their own accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there's an individual module for that purpose, but I guess you could take a look at Drupal's [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/url) method or [hook_url_inbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) to help your purpose.