# Redirect 'user' and 'user/uid' to 'users/name'

Tags: 6, hooks, users

I have been trying to redirect the default user url of '/user' to the url alias of '/users/username'.

If i go to '/user/uid' it redirects properly but if i type in '/user' the url doesn't redirect.

Using hook_preprocess_user_profile() I can print arg(0) and arg(1) with drupal_set_message() and it display that arg(1) exists as the uid on '/user'.

I have tried

```
function mymodule_preprocess_user_profile(&$vars) {
  global $user;
  //print_r($vars);
  if (arg(0) == 'user' && arg(1) == $user->uid){
    //drupal_set_message('0'.arg(0).'1'.arg(1));
    drupal_goto("users/$user->name");
  }
}
```

but this end up in an endless redirect. Is it possible to even accomplish this?

Comment: the pathautho module does that, see this previous question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14281/user-urls-based-on-the-usernames

Answer (score 1):

By redirecting `/user` you'll be redirecting the login page to a user page.  When someone goes to `/user` and logs in they are automatically redirected to `/user/username`.  Unless you have login disabled(not advised) I can't see what you want to achieve, can you explain further?

Redirects are best handled by the [path redirect](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) module

or using rules in `.htacces` or `etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Comment: I think what the OP is trying to do is make /user redirect /user/username when a user is logged in.  Currently if you're logged in /user == /user/logged-in-users-name.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I realise if you visit /user, the $_GET['q'] (which produces the arg's) returns /user/uid, so it looks like you are on the /user/uid page even though you are not.

I placed the code below into my themes template.php and it will redirect /user to /user/uid. If you have URL aliases enabled, this will then redirect to that.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$page) {

  if (request_uri() == base_path().'user' && $page['user']->uid != 0 ) {
    $path = 'user/' . $page['user']->uid;
    drupal_goto('user/1');
  }
}
```

I wanted to do the same on my site, but I use the me-alias module. The following code worked in my themes template.php. Re the above problem of /user looking like /user/uid, this is okay in this case because I am going to a new path (/user/me), instead of being stuck in the /user/uid loop. This also changes all the /user/uid/* pages too.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$page) {

  $path = $_GET['q'];
  if (arg(0) == 'user' && arg(1) == $page['user']->uid) {
    $path = str_replace('user/' . arg(1), 'user/me', $path);
    drupal_goto($path);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect by using trigger. Drupal provide you basic functionality to do the changes after login by few steps..

1. Open with your admin by given url : admin/config/system/actions
2. Chose from CREATE AN ADVANCED ACTION and select Redirect to URL..
3. Type Label like - Redirect to URL - users #
4. URL - user
5. Now enable module triger in admin/modules page.
6. Go to - admin/structure/trigger/user
7. Choose an action from TRIGGER: AFTER A USER HAS LOGGED IN
8. And assign to Redirect to URL - users #

Now these 8 steps will short out your problem. Logout and again login to check functionality.

Thanks..
Vishal Nigam